# Docker run multiple instances of container without --scale

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml which is running a simple web server. I want to create multiple instances of the container without `--scaling` in the start command. This is how I currently start multiple instances of the container `docker-composer up -d --scale appserver=2`.

Ideally, I would love to put some kind of instruction in the docker-compose.yml to do this. Below is an example of the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  appserver:
    image: nimmis/apache
  haproxy:
    image: eeacms/haproxy
    ports:
      - '80:5000'
      - '1936:1936'
    environment:
      BACKENDS: 'appserver_1:80 appserver_2:80 appserver_3:80'
      DNS_ENABLED: 'true'
      LOG_LEVEL: info
```

Note here that I am only trying to multiple instances of `appserver` service.

Answer (score 2):

Docker compose doesn't support the `deploy` section, but if you switch to a single node Swarm Mode (as easy as running `docker swarm init`) you can deploy with:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack_name
```

using the following yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  appserver:
    image: nimmis/apache
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
  haproxy:
    image: eeacms/haproxy
    ports:
      - '80:5000'
      - '1936:1936'
    environment:
      BACKENDS: 'appserver_1:80 appserver_2:80 appserver_3:80'
      DNS_ENABLED: 'true'
      LOG_LEVEL: info
```